# Sync SOLR with another repository

Tags: solr, handler, synchronization

I need to keep SOLR indexes in sync with another repository (SQL DB) . SOLR being the source : all operations (Update,Delete,'Insert') on documents are done in SOLR and fired from a third party software on which I have no control.

I had to do it quickly, so did 'something that just works' :

2 scheduled jobs:

- the first is for newly inserted and updated docs in SOLR: a simple
  search query brings me the docs that need to be synchronized, so it
  is easy to make the same into my database.
- the second is for deletes:
  This gets all IDs in SOLR and compare them to the ones in DB, the
  extra ones are being deleted.

I keep these in separated job for more flexibility (enable / disable through config), and also because the sync schedule is different for each one.

I am not satisfied with my solution, I did not have much time to dive deep in the SORL documentation back then.
But now , I am wondering if there is/are better way(s) to do it. Ideally to get nearly real time sync and fire it on demand.

May be event Handlers in SOLR configuration ?

I think updates won't be an issue with event handler, if I can hook in the update event and fire the same operation in the DB. (If anyone could confirm if this is the best approach)

For delete and this is the most required, because the comparison I do between IDs is heavy (huge DB and huge document sets in SOLR).

Is there any event handler in SOLR that would let me know which documents are being deleted (when delete query is submitted) ?

I thought asking here may save me time.
Also, if possible to point me to some samples would be great. 
(Preferably using .NET but I am open to do it in JAVA since it is the framework of SOLR or mix the two.)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an update hook available in Solr that allows you to run a binary:

```
<!-- The RunExecutableListener executes an external command.
         exe  - the name of the executable to run
         dir  -  dir to use as the current working directory. default="."
         wait - the calling thread waits until the executable returns.
                default="true"
         args - the arguments to pass to the program.  default=nothing
         env  - environment variables to set.  default=nothing
      -->
    <!-- A postCommit event is fired after every commit
      -->
    <listener event="postCommit" class="solr.RunExecutableListener">
      <str name="exe">snapshooter</str>
      <str name="dir">solr/bin</str>
      <bool name="wait">true</bool>
      <!--
      <arr name="args"> <str>arg1</str> <str>arg2</str> </arr>
      <arr name="env"> <str>MYVAR=val1</str> </arr>
        -->
    </listener>
  </updateHandler>
```

See the [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#A.22Update.22_Related_Event_Listeners)

Comment: Thanks @qux , but how do I pass the parameters from the update 'context' to the bin, for example If want to know what kind of update really happened , may be also the document (or the set of documents) involved in the update. Do you have any idea how can this achieved ?

Comment: You could softdelete using a field named deletionDate and use this field to sync the remote DB. You can always hard delete afterwards to clean up.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I was out of town, 
I don't get the custom field part? how do I achieve this? 
My problem is that I don't have control over the operations done in SOLR  (all triggered via a 3rd party software), I can only query SOLR to check for what exists there. To my knowledge, there no field that can tell what is the deletion date (if the documnet is still in SOLR). so I do now is really querying all document, and check for the missing Ids (compared to my DB).

Comment: I did not may be explain it well, but I want just to know which documents were deleted. This should be really easy to achieve since this information (or at least the number of deleted document is on admin panel). I thought the best way would be to get notified every time a  delete operation is about to happen (or did happen), but this seems to be not easy/possible to do with the event handler in SOLR. 
Any suggestions ?